# pandas python using head() generic function

Tags: python, pandas, head

I am a beginner to python,in our college they assigned a project i.e. to display timetables of our department using pandas python.Iam presenting my program as menu driven program.But the problem is Iam not able to display my timetables in a grid pattern using head() in if else loop..can u let me know where I am i wrong..??
Sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

loop=1
while loop==1:
    print('WELCOME TO CBIT')
    print('1.IT 2')
    print('2.EXIT')
    print()
    choice=input('Enter ur choice')
    choice=int(choice)
    if choice==1:
        df=input('tt is')
        df=pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx')
        df.head()
    elif choice==2:
        loop=0
```

Answer (score 0):

## use this code. it will work. before using this code go to command prompt and write execute this command `pip install xlrd` I am sure it will work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

loop=1
while loop==1:
    print('WELCOME TO CBIT')
    print('1.IT 2')
    print('2.EXIT')
    choice=int(raw_input('Input:'))
    if choice==1:
        #df=input('tt is')
        df=pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx') #enter file name here
        print(df)
        #df.head()
    elif choice==2:
        loop=0
```

Comment: if it solves your problem then accept the answer and upvote it

Comment: Thank you Sir.But I want my output to be displayed with border lines Sir.I got the table with border lines when used head() individually.i.e by using the code: import pandas as pd import numpy as np df=pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx) df.head().But while using this code in menu driven program,I am not getting the output in grid pattern.Iam getting the output but without any lines.

Comment: pandas is not capable of displaying the complete data frame at a time

Answer (score 0):

Add a print statement: `print(df.head())` . If you are looking for a nicer display you can have a look at [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html).